# Zariski-Lipman conjecture and locally-free tangent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The Zariski-Lipman conjecture asserts that, in the case of $X$ being a complex variety, if the tangent sheaf $TX$ is locally-free then $X$ is smooth. This has been proved in some particular cases.

Now let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $k=\bar{k}$.

Is it true that whenever $X$ is smooth then $TX$ is locally-free?

If not, which ones are reasonable hypothesis on $X$ to ensure the locally-freeness of its tangent sheaf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true. (This should be intuitively clear: after all, the tangent sheaf is meant to generalise the tangent bundle of a manifold.) A reference is Hartshorne Theorem II.8.15.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I decided not to trust my intuition too much any longer, but in this case it was correct ;-)

Comment: What happens if the variety is not smooth?

Comment: @Abramo: the Theorem in Hartshorne says that, in that case, the _cotangent_ sheaf fails to be locally free. Can the dual of something not locally free be locally free? I guess so, but I don't know an example off the top of my head. (Edit: well, I guess I do.)

Comment: Maybe an example exists, but anyway I guess in general the tangent sheaf does not need to be locally free in the case of a singular variety

Comment: Here is a concrete [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156098/tangent-sheaf-of-a-specific-nodal-curve) of the tangent sheaf on a transversal intersection of smooth curves. @Asal Beag Dubh: Yes, it may happen. Take a smooth surface $X$, $p \in X$ closed point and $j: U = X \setminus P \hookrightarrow X$ natural inclusion, $E$ locally free sheaf on $U$. Then $j_* E^{\vee\vee}$ is locally free on $X$ even if not necessarily $j_* E$ is locally free. (also cf. http://mathoverflow.net/a/22166/23507)

Comment: Dear finite: thanks for that example.